# Fatal Error: Class not Found when using namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces

I have been trying to use namespaces for the first time in ages and I am running into the below problem. I am currently using Composer for a PSR-4 autoloader and I keep getting the error:
`Fatal error: Class 'API\Library\Config' not found in C:\wamp64\www\project\src\index.php on line 14`

composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "API\\": "src",
        "API\\Library\\": "src/Library",
        "API\\Controllers\\": "src/Application/Controllers"
    }
}
```

src/index.php

```
namespace API;
include_once('vendor/autoload.php');
use API\Library\Config;
$config = new Config(); //line 18
```

The Folder layout is as such:

[image: folder layout]

Comment: Did you try "$ composer dump-autoload" to re-generate the autoload file?

Comment: yes I did, sorry I will update OP to confirm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because src is the parent folder. Ideally vendor would be in the same directory as src.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "API\\": "",
        "API\\Library\\": "Library",
        "API\\Controllers\\": "Application/Controllers"
    }
}
```

Would work, or you should restructure your directories.

Also you can leave out `"API\\Library\\": "Library",` as it will be picked up by `"API\\": "",`

Comment: seems to be working, didn't think about the position of vendor being an issue so thank you!

Comment: np, easy mistake and we all been there :)